# IE Object doesn't support this action all versions when trying to pass 'this' in a function constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have built a little voting app so people can vote on questions and publish to twitter.

I have a twitter function that I use 'new' to instantiate and pass 'this' of the parent through so it has access to some vars:

```
    var APP =  {}

    APP.Main = function() {
         this.tweet = new APP.Tweet(this)
    }

    APP.Tweet = function() {

    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var app = new APP.Main()
    });
```

However throws an error 'Object doesn't support this action'...

It works in every other browser but not any version of IE? The Tweet code is in a different file but none of the code is called until the docready event is fired?

Thanks

Comment: That single line of code isn't nearly enough information.

Comment: Anyway we can see the constructor of the class `APP` and it's method `Tweet`?

Comment: The good news is your code sample works fine in IE (http://jsfiddle.net/FMbG3/2/, tested in IE9). The bad news is you didn't supply an example that actually reproduces your problem.